# Handleing Nodejs crashes in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have written a Nodejs application that I plan on deploying to Heroku. The Nodejs app has mysql package installed and has lot of async query execution. When I one of my query fails and Nodejs throws error I simply restart the server. What happens when events like these happen when I deploy my Nodejs application to Heroku.

How do people handle Nodejs server stopping or crashing in production?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to aim to handle all errors so you don't run into an issue where the app goes down, but if it does you can always restart via the command line interface using the command:

```
heroku restart -a app_name
```

To avoid crashes, make sure you have error handling in your app.js, for example:

```
const errorHandlers = require('./handlers/errorHandlers');
app.use(errorHandlers.productionErrors);
```

Where errorHandlers.productionErrors looks like:

```
exports.productionErrors = (err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
};
```